# Flutter schedule local notification does not work

Tags: flutter, flutter-local-notification

I am trying to create a notification at a certain time but it is not working. The code does not throw any error but no notification is displayed on the device.
I am using [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications)

Code that generates the notification:

```
Future<void> showNotification(
  int hour, int id, String title, String body) async {
await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
  id,
  title,
  body,
  _convertTime(hour),
  const NotificationDetails(
    android: AndroidNotificationDetails('main_channel', 'Main Channel',
        channelDescription: "ashwin",
        importance: Importance.max,
        priority: Priority.max),
    iOS: IOSNotificationDetails(
      sound: 'default.wav',
      presentAlert: true,
      presentBadge: true,
      presentSound: true,
    ),
  ),
  uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
      UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
  androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
);
}
```

_converTime function code:

```
TZDateTime _convertTime(int hour) {
final tz.TZDateTime now = tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local);
tz.TZDateTime scheduleDate =
    tz.TZDateTime(tz.local, now.year, now.month, now.day, hour, 47);
return scheduleDate;
}
```

The result of the function is correct and is as follows: *2022-07-14 12:47:00.000Z*

However, if instead of using this function, I change it to

```
Future<void> showNotification(
  int hour, int id, String title, String body) async {
await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
  id,
  title,
  body,
  // _convertTime(hour), // this does not work
  tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local).add(Duration(seconds: 1)), // this work
  const NotificationDetails(
    android: AndroidNotificationDetails('main_channel', 'Main Channel',
        channelDescription: "ashwin",
        importance: Importance.max,
        priority: Priority.max),
    // iOS details
    iOS: IOSNotificationDetails(
      sound: 'default.wav',
      presentAlert: true,
      presentBadge: true,
      presentSound: true,
    ),
  ),

  uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
      UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
  androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
);
}
```

I don't understand what could be happening.
I appreciate any help in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this one, remove some properties if you don't want them...

```
 Future zonedScheduleNotification(String note, DateTime date, occ) async {
        // IMPORTANT!!
        //tz.initializeTimeZones(); --> call this before using tz.local (ideally put it in your init state)
        
        int id = math.Random().nextInt(10000);
        log(date.toString());
        log(tz.TZDateTime.parse(tz.local, date.toString())
            .toString());
        try {
          await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
            id,
            occ,
            note,
            tz.TZDateTime.parse(tz.local, date.toString()),
            NotificationDetails(
              android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
                  'your channel id', 'your channel name',
                  channelDescription: 'your channel description',
                  largeIcon: DrawableResourceAndroidBitmap("logo"),
                  icon: "ic_launcher",
                  playSound: true,
                  sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound('bell_sound')),
            ),
            androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
            uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
                UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
          );
          return id;
        } catch (e) {
          log("Error at zonedScheduleNotification----------------------------$e");
          if (e ==
              "Invalid argument (scheduledDate): Must be a date in the future: Instance of 'TZDateTime'") {
            Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Select future date");
          }
          return -1;
        }
      }
```

Comment: Thanks Ninad. This works just like I wanted.

Answer (score -1):

Try this again.

```
tz.TZDateTime _convertTime(int hour) {
  final tz.TZDateTime now = tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local);

  tz.TZDateTime scheduleDate =
      tz.TZDateTime(tz.local, now.year, now.month, now.day, hour, 47);

  return scheduleDate;
}
```

Comment: This is how I had it in the beginning but I don't want any notification to be added if you have selected a time earlier than the current one. Still, if I leave it as it is it still doesn't work.
Thanks anyway.

Comment: This is how i have it in the code right now